# How to clean najas ( نجس ) Clothes according to Shariah?

Tags: sharia, sunnah, sunni, taharah

How can one clean clothes, bedsheets etc after being made najas by Urine, Natural discharges etc. So that they can be used for Prayers again.
What way / method Shariah teaches us for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I found a forum [post](http://ashraf786.proboards.com/index.cgi?board=sib&action=display&thread=3905), that quotes '*To A Muslim Daughter, The rules of
cleanliness* by **Ata Ul Mustafa jamil**.' But I can find no such book. I've repeated what is said there with corrections and aditions that I have found on various islamic sites

> There are two types of najasat (uncleanliness) Najasat Khaliza and
> Najasat Khafifa.
>
> ### Najasat Khaliza
>
> This is intense uncleanliness and has strict orders,
> The following are examples of this:-
>
> Excreta, Urine, Blood, puss, Blood from haiz, nifaas and istihaza,
> Mani and mazi, water from yes and breasts due to pain, Mouthful of
> vomit, Infants urine, Infants mouthful of vomit of milk, fat and meat
> of the dead, Milk and fat of haraam animals, Dogs saliva, Excreta and
> urine of haraam animals, Excreta of Halal animals, All kinds of wine.
>
> If the body or cloth gets dirty with Najasat Khaliza more than a *size
> of a coin* then it is farz to clean it. Salah offered without cleaning
> will not be valid. If it is the same size of a small coin then it is
> wajib to clean it it is also wajib to repeat salah offered without
> cleaning it. If it is less than a coin then it is sunnah to clean it
> salah will be counted without cleaning.
>
> ### Najasat Khafifa
>
> This is minor uncleanliness and does not have strict orders. The
> following are examples of Najasat Khafifa:-
>
> Urine of halal animals such as cows and sheep's, urine of a horse,
> Excreta of haraam birds such as crows and eagles, Gall bladder of
> halal animals.
>
> If less than a quarter of a part of the body or clothing becomes dirty
> with Najasat Khafifa then it is allowed to offer salat without
> cleaning. However if it is more than quarter then it is wajib to clean
> before performing salaat.
>
> #### Methods of cleaning Najasat
>
> Najasat such as excreta and blood if it can be removed by washing
> once/twice the cloth will be clean but it is best to wash it three
> times. Najasat such as urine (including child's urine) should be
> washed three times.
>
> Clothing contaminated with Najasat should be washed separately from
> those which have no Najasat. Prior to loading the machine the Najasat
> such as Mani and excreta should be removed.
>
> #### Najasat on the body
>
> It is adequate to wash the body three times so that the Najasat is
> completely removed.
>
> #### Najasat on utensils
>
> Also wash the utensils three times.

Here I found a [difference of opinion](http://islamqa.info/en/ref/65617) compared to the above quoted text:

> Narrated by al-Bukhaari (5478) and Muslim (3567) from Abu Tha’labah al-Khushani who said: I said, “O Prophet of Allaah, I live in a land where there are some of the People of the Book; can we eat from their vessels?” He said: “As for what you said about the People of the Book, if you can find anything else, do not eat from their vessels, but if you cannot find anything else then wash them and eat from them.”

Here no stipulation on number of times is given.

> #### Najasat on the carpet The najasat should be scrubbed off and wash in the
>
> normal manner.
>
> #### Najasat on shoes If shoes become unclean with excreta etc then they
>
> should be cleaned, once the najasat has scraped off whilst drying.
>
> #### Najasat on atta (flour) If a dog or mouse touches flour (either in wet
>
> or dry form) then the part which was in contact should be removed, the
> rest will be clean.
>
> This information was taken from *To A Muslim Daughter, The rules of
> cleanliness* by **Ata Ul Mustafa jamil**.

Unfortunately I cannot find any corroborating material on the subject, however insha Allah this will be sufficient until I, or someone else can find more information.

Comment: Could people please help me improve this answer?